# Table of values only

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table with month in one column and then sales in that month in the next column. Some months have no sales. I want to create a new table based using formulas so I only see the months with sales along with their sales. Such that;

Apr - 500
May - 500
June -
July -
Aug - 500

etc becomes

Apr - 500
May - 500
Aug - 500

Answer (score 1):

Use the FILTER function:

[image]

The formula in cell I1:

```
=FILTER(F1:G5,G1:G5<>"")
```

EDIT:

If you don't have the FILTER function, you can use an Advanced Filter on the "Sort & Filter" group on the Data tab on the Ribbon.

Configure a small filter table, which include a column without a header that has a formula that refers to a cell in the amount column in your data. The formula in cell K2 in the screenshot below is:

```
=G2<>""
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me as the FILTER function isn't rolled out until July 2020.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: The version is Excel 365

Comment: Ok, before July you can use Advanced Filter. I edited the answer to demonstrate how.

Comment: It has to be a formula, otherwise it would be easier to use a PivotTable and refresh it based on change in data table. An AdvancedFilter hides rows which would not work for the project I am working on.

Comment: Then I recommend using a pivot table. 

What have you tried to figure this out yourself?

Comment: I don't want to use PivotTables as I can't use to code to refresh the table.That's why I need something formula based.

Answer (score 1):

For older versions use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A$1:A$5)/($B$1:$B$5<>""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Put that in the first cell and copy over one column and down till you get blanks.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make this work if the data is moved, in my OP I should have stated that the table can sit anywhere in the sheet and there are headings and title above it.

Answer (score 1):

*You need an Array (CSE) formula:*

[image]

- Formula in cell `Q36`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(N$36:N$43,SMALL(IF($O$36:$O$43<>"",ROW($O$36:$O$43)-ROW($O$36)+1),ROWS(Q$35:Q35))),"")}
  ```
- *Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill across.*

---

**:Edited:**

```
 {=SMALL(IF(O$36:O$43<>"",ROW(O$36:O$43)-ROW(O$36)+1),ROWS(Q$35:Q35))}
```

- Above formula, if is an array formula, then returns Row number of non blanks values from `O36 to O43`, otherwise gets only the first value's Row number `1`.

**Check this explains that, how it works.**

[image]

- An Array (CSE) formula in cell `V36`:

  ```
  {=SMALL(IF(O$36:O$43<>"",ROW(O$36:O$43)-ROW(O$36)+1),ROWS(V$35:V35))}
  ```
- Formula in cell `W36`:

  `=INDEX(N$36:N$43,$V36)`
- Gets correct month name match with non blank cells, where `INDEX` gets order from `V36 to V40`.

And if you fill it Right then Down you get,

[image]

- *`IFERROR` replaces #NUM error with blanks.*

*So that the proper combination of INDEX and SMALL gets the month's name along with related values in desire order.*

- *Adjust cell references in all above formula as needed.*

Comment: Can you do it without an array formula?

Comment: @Naz,, check the edited part of my post, help you to understand the importance of an Array formula.

Comment: I will look at it, I do understand the importance of Array formulas. The big problem I have with them is when other people using the spreadsheet don't and try to change the range in the formula and don#t press CSE and break it. That's why i avoid them. Thanks.

Comment: @Naz,, while changing sheet or data range one has to careful about change cell reference accordingly in the formula. Now if U find my post is the answer you were looking for then you may accept is as Answer as well Up vote also, Remember for such a situation Array formula is/are the ultimate choice. ☺

Answer (score -1):

Use a pivot table.

Step 1: create pivot table

[image]

Step 2: go to row labels -> value filters -> does not equal
[image]

Step 3: enter 0
[image]

Step 4: click ok, your pivot table should now look like this:

[image]

Comment: If your data is detailed list of sales that could add to zero, then you may have to change the value filter to `not between` and use values like `-.005` and `.005` this will take away any excel rounding errors...

Comment: @gms100 As stated the answer is suppose to be formula based, whilst a Pivot Table will provide a solution, if the data changes the pivot table will not automatically update and I am not able to use code in this instance.